# (Advice) Home Automation Project (Domotic mobile home)

Tags: home-automation

I have a project that I hope to accomplish in the near future.
I want to transform a mobile home into automation mobile home.

The elements that make up my project are the following:
[image: schema of hardware]

My idea is to supply the home with a solar installation, disregarding their potential (we can discuss the autonomy of the system later, uses and consumptions).

The idea is to keep an Arduino always running in order to monitorize the home and provide remote administration.(like geolocation, camera and sensors control,power management for hardware ...)

The laptop can be out of the system (when I take it with me). It could be connected to a secondary monitor.
The docker provide an easy way to charge the laptop, connect devices and provide a WOL utility.

The Arduino could have differents components like Ethernet, own battery, gps... And It could switch on/off the camera and sensors.
The laptop could be powered on/off by WOL and administrate remotely.

The camera could have a microSD to save media and it can be manipulated with Arduino by a remote connection.
Arduino could get info about sensors too(as proximity).

I have some doubts:

1. Instead of using WOL , we could use Arduino to wake up the laptop?
2. It's possible to connect the laptop and the arduino by wlan or ethernet interface? or we need to wire it (usb...)?

Thanks for the attention, I await your answer.

Comment: 1. `no` because you only show a network connection between the arduino and the laptop .... 2. yes and no

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @jsotola Well technically arduino can send WOL packet to the laptop.

Comment: Cool ! What have you done do far, and which bit of it are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Dou you really want to use an Arduino for this? At least the Atmega based arduinos are not capable of handling any "media".  Why not using a raspberry Pi or similar. I think that would make much more sense

Comment: If i can use Arduino than other powerful devices better ,  in order to save battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino is not built or powerful enough to handle things like cameras and high-speed 4g connections for remote administration. I would suggest using something like a [Raspberry PI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) 3 as it would be much better suited to the job.
I would recommend asking this question again on the raspberry pi exchange.

Comment: But I only would use it for power on/off devices, move the point of view of the camera , and detect activation of sensors like proximity (Boolean) and thinks like that. Not processing video or these heavy tasks. I suppose the ip camera has the capacity to record video and so on. And if the PC is on the system could do other heavy tasks. I thought that with Arduino was enough for these uses.

Comment: It would be fine for the uses you just stated but configuring the arduino and the PC to work together would be quite difficult. (Like how would you get the recorded video to the computer?) Also, your computer would need to always be there so if you wanted to use your laptop in your house and moniter the sensors, there would be a problem. I think a single one board computer like a PI would be easier and more effective.

Comment: Okei thanks, I will study use PI.

Comment: If you want to save battery, you can also use a smaller Pi board, like the Raspberry Pi Zero W. Though it has no LAN, but WLAN.

Comment: Yep, under clocking the raspberry pi is also an option but you can discuss those details on the pi stack exchange/forum